# Draw Styling circle in Joint js

Tags: javascript, html, css, jointjs

I am using Joint Js for my custom drawing tool.
And I have some problems with drawing the element on the picture below, i think it should be the Circle element with custom border, but i don't know how to do border like this.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem?

**Needed Element**

[image]

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot, a find the another solution but yours is quite simple

Comment: If you tested it and it works plz accept it as an answer of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy.

You just need a shape of type: `basic.Image`

I created and the base64 picture that you need.

Just paste this code to your Stencil and you are done.

```
new joint.shapes.basic.Image({
        attrs: {
            image: { width: 50, height: 50, 'xlink:href': 'data:image/png;base64,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' },
            text: { text: 'Circle Shape', fill: '#000000', 'font-size': 12, stroke: '#000000', 'stroke-width': 1}
        }
    })
```